# (Octave) error: feval: the symbol `java_exit' is not valid as a function

Tags: octave

I am getting this error while exit from octave

error: feval: the symbol `java_exit' is not valid as a function

I understand it is a wrong way to terminate a java application. Is this an Octave bug? Is there any fix? The application terminates, but that is just annoying. I do not know if I will have more problems in the future.
I run octave from remotely on a linux machine through PuTTY on a windows machine.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: show us the code. Explain the problem better. You get that error when you try to exit Octave or when doing something specific? Do you have the java package installed? What have you done to find the origin of the problem and what have you found?

Comment: Hi, I must really improve my requests... There is no code, I only get that error when I 'exit' Octave. The JVM is installed, but in a not standard directory. If i redirect JAVA_HOME to the correct folder, nothing improves. I do not understand if it is an error or just a warning. Octave quits anyway.

Comment: Octave does not use java at all. My guess is that you have Octave's java package installed. Remove it or unload it if you don't need it.